# Cómo insertar valores en un v-modal dinámico (en loop)

Tags: javascript, html

tengo el siguiente código:

```
<tr v-for="(item, index) in items">
  <td data-label="Nº">{{ index + 1 }}</td>
  <td data-label="Producto"><input name="p_nombre[]" type="text" v-model="item.description" /></td>
  <td data-label="Cantidad"><input name="p_cantidad[]" type="number" min="0" v-model="item.quantity" /></td>
  <td data-label="Precio"><div class="cell-with-input">{{ invoiceCurrency.symbol }} <input name="p_precio[]" type="number" min="0" v-model="item.price" /></div></td>
  <td data-label="Descuento"><input name="p_descuento[]" type="number" min="0" v-model="item.descuento" /></td>
  <td data-label="Impuesto"><input name="p_impuesto[]" type="number" min="0" v-model="item.impuesto" /></td>
  <td data-label="Total">{{ (item.price * item.quantity) - (item.descuento * item.quantity) + ((item.price * item.quantity) * item.impuesto / 100 ) }}
  <input name="p_total[]" class="text-right" type="hidden" min="0" max="100" v-model="p_total" /></td>
  <td class="text-right"><button class="btn btn-danger" v-on:click="deleteItem(index)"><i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i></button></td>
</tr>
```

quisiera que cada input name="p_total[]" que se crea muestre su respectivo valor

```
{{ (item.price * item.quantity) - (item.descuento * item.quantity) + ((item.price * item.quantity) * item.impuesto / 100 ) }}
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Answer (score 0):

Aqui la solución:

```
<tr v-for="(item, index) in items">
  <td data-label="Nº">{{ index + 1 }}</td>
  <td data-label="Producto"><input name="p_nombre[]" type="text" v-model="item.description" /></td>
  <td data-label="Cantidad"><input name="p_cantidad[]" type="number" min="0" v-model="item.quantity" /></td>
  <td data-label="Precio"><div class="cell-with-input">{{ invoiceCurrency.symbol }} <input name="p_precio[]" type="number" min="0" v-model="item.price" /></div></td>
  <td data-label="Descuento"><input name="p_descuento[]" type="number" min="0" v-model="item.descuento" /></td>
  <td data-label="Impuesto"><input name="p_impuesto[]" type="number" min="0" v-model="item.impuesto" /></td>
  <td data-label="Total">{{ item.total = ((item.price * item.quantity) - (item.descuento * item.quantity) + ((item.price * item.quantity) * item.impuesto / 100 )) }}
  <input name="p_total[]" class="text-right" type="hidden" min="0" max="100" v-model="item.total" /></td>
  <td class="text-right"><button class="btn btn-danger" v-on:click="deleteItem(index)"><i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i></button></td>
</tr>
```